# SharePoint - set reply-to in a workflow

Tags: sharepoint, email, workflow

I have my SharePoint server set to send e-mails from a dedicated e-mail box. However, I have a workflow that sends an e-mail out to a particular group, and I want replies from that group to go instead to a different e-mail box.

I know that BCC is a hidden field in a workflow that can be changed; I don't see anything for reply-to. So I'm not sure that there's an easy way to do it. What options do I have? I know there's a tool on CodePlex that does a lot with e-mail activities, but I think that might be overkill.

I appreciate any suggestions, advice, etc. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't specify a reply-to email address using SharePoint Designer out of the box. Since it is a workflow, you can create a [Custom Workflow action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629922.aspx) that would allow you to do anything you want (including send an email with a reply-to address). This is a pretty involved process and will require C# code.